# Image not loading in the ImageView from InputStream

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to obtain the images from the contacts ,so the problem is that image in not being showed.I have found the code on [ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.html) ,but I'm unable to load id.

```
 public InputStream openPhoto(long contactId) {
        Uri contactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, contactId);
        Uri photoUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(contactUri, ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(photoUri,
                new String[] {ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.PHOTO}, null, null, null);
        if (cursor == null) {
            return null;
        }
        try {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                byte[] data = cursor.getBlob(0);
                if (data != null) {
                    return new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
                }
            }
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }
        return null;
    }





Profile.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(openPhoto(322)));
```

Comment: And does openPhoto() return null? Tell what happens!

Comment: `if (data != null) {
                    return new ByteArrayInputStream(data);` You are not closing the cursor.